# I want to call jquery function until viewbag fill up some data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have controller action , which fill up viewbag .

```
 ViewBag.IsDownloadPDF = "true";
```

I have function which i calling in $(document).ready(function ()) function .

```
function checkdata()
{
 alert('Hi');
}
```

I want to call checkdata function until viewbag data not found .

I am appreciate if i will get my correct answer .

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, however it seems like a flawed problem as the ViewBag is built on the server so JS cannot directly interact with it.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan ,ok . any object from server side , i can access in jquery .any object exist like that ?

Comment: So if Viewbag.isdownloadpdf = true, then you want the CheckData to run?

Comment: yes . u got my point what i want earlier .

Answer (score 0):

I know this aint beautiful code but cant you do this?

```
@if (ViewBag.IsDownloadPDF == "true")
{
    <script>
        //Either this
        function checkdata()
        {
         alert('Hi');
        }
        checkdata();

        //Or this
        checkdata();
    </script>
}
```